# Simultaneously enable gzip and $STR_REPLACE in CGI in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, cgi, mod-fcgid, php-cgi

I have a code in my CGI script for text replacement (for example replace 'red' with 'blue')

```
$STR_SEARCH='red'
$STR_REPLACE='blue'
```

I am using the below code in `.htaccess` for enable replace function: (RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding)

This work fine. But when I want to use gzip for compression, gzip does not work. If I disable the replace, gzip works fine. Please help me understand how I can enable the replace and gzip simultaneously?

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess ?